# Standard Calendar in Autosys

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

How to find out the calendar days and months for a particular job in autosys? Do we have any autosys command for that? Any one please let me know.

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the job name, you can find out the calendar name from Jil(job definition) and get the required details(days, month..) from the preview of calendar.

Command to view the preview an calendar:

```
autocal_asc
```

steps to view the preview an standard calendar:

- Step 1: autocal_asc
- step 2: Give option [1].
- step 3: Give option [5] (List dates for a Calendar)
- step 4: Paste the calendar name.
- step 5: Now you can view the preview of standard calendar.

steps to view the preview an Extended calendar:

- Step 1: autocal_asc
- Step 2: Give option [2].
- Step 3: Give option [5] (Preview an Extended Calendar).
- Step 4: Paste the calendar name.
- Step 5: Now you can view the preview an Extended calendar.

Regards,
Kaliraja.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful in finding out the calender for the job.